# How to port Python slicing assignment syntax to JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to rewrite a Python library to TypeScript.

I am having trouble porting this line from [this repository](https://github.com/mCodingLLC/prime_sieve/blob/93e0769e4a6468d41ebf85a3a716fefcf8791ded/prime_sieve/list.py#L34).:

```py
is_prime[start - segment_min::pk] = repeat(False, len(range(start - segment_min, segment_len, pk)))
```

I know it's Python slicing assignment, but don't know how to port it to JS/TS.

How do I do this in JavaScript/Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple slicing assignment `target[t_start:t_end] = source[s_start:s_end]` can be achieved in JS using a combination of the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) Array methods:

```
target.splice(tStart, tEnd-tStart, ...source.slice(sStart, sEnd));
```

However, JavaScript does not support a `step` slicing, for that you'll have to write a loop yourself.